# How to setup gmap maps on nodes (using location fields)

Tags: google-maps

I use the [gmap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) and the [location](http://drupal.org/project/location) to show maps in nodes by adding the **location field** to the node content type.

Let's say I have 2 content types: **Pubs** and **Restaurants**
Each one of them have a location field which allows me to show a map for the nodes.
So far so god.

My problem is that I see no way to setup the map (zoom, marker, ...) in a different way for each one of the content types.

Let's say I want to set the zoom for Pubs' maps to 12 and the zoom for restaurants' maps to 10.

The only way I see to setup the maps is in admin/config/services/gmap, but these setting affects maps in all nodes of all content types.

I need to customize maps for each content type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [OpenLayers](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers/) instead of Gmap you can set up different maps for different fields. It's more complicated, but with more options.

Comment: I've never used OpenLayer. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Geolocation](https://drupal.org/project/geolocation) module. It allows you to add a location field (you can then easily select a location using Google Maps in node editing screen) in any content type.

The module then allows you to display the location on a node in various styles (including Google Maps).